# Spring MVC 3: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: spring-mvc

Hi
Could someone help me understand what am I doing wrong in the following code due to which I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:408)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.signUp_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(signUp_jsp.java:179)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.signUp_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(signUp_jsp.java:111)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.signUp_jsp._jspService(signUp_jsp.java:74)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    ... 59 more
```

**UserManagementController.java**

```
@Controller
public class UserManagementController { 
    //displays sign up page(GET)
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/signUp.html")
    public ModelAndView signUpForm() {
        System.out.println("Sign up");
        return new ModelAndView("/signUp", "user", new User());
    }

}
```

**signUp.jsp**

```
<body>
    <h3>Sign up</h3>
    <table>
        <form:form commandName="user" >
            <tr>
                <td>First name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="firstName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="lastName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><form:input path="username"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><form:input path="password"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </form:form>
    </table>
</body>
```

Could someone help me understand it?

Thanks.

Comment: could you check if there indeed exists a request attribute called `user` when the jsp is rendered? (use `<c:out />` for example)

Comment: @Bozho: I have a propery `private boolean enabled = true;`, with a getter method for it, on my User domain object that I am using here as a backing object. When I try to retrieve `${user.enabled}` on `signUp.jsp` it doesnt show anything, so I think there indeed is no `'user'` available as a request attribute. And I am not able to understand why?

Comment: @Bozho: I was able to get the `signUp.jsp` displayed to test `${user.enabled}` because I had commented out the complete `<table>` element which had the `<form:form>` tag inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was mistakenly using the wrong import for `ModelAndView`.
I was supposed to use `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView` but the one I was mistakenly using was `org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView`.

I've got the code working now.

Thanks :)

Comment: +1 for solving it yourself. Please accept your own answer when you can.